# Expandable list in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trapped . please write how to write a code for Expandable list in xml layout in android.

I have to create  a static page that contains a expandable list ,tabs ,images and some other things please help me

Thank you

Comment: please show us, what you have tried?

Comment: Hey siva I haven't done anything because I do not know how to code expandable list in android please write some code for this . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like this:

```
<ExpandableListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ex_list">
```

?

Comment: yes sure but it didn't worked  please write a sample code for a selector. thank you

Comment: you need selector for expandable list items?

Comment: Then you must set standart or create custon adapter. I can't understand your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have build a super light solution recently . It's worth to have a look at :

https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion

[image]